# How to switch users on git bash, already tried git config username and email

Tags: git

So far, I have two git accounts that I use, one for my school, and one for my personal endeavors. I am looking to push some changes to git repo. Now I changed git username and user email using the commands noted below, then I  git cloned files I was interested in making changes to, and I wanted to git push those changes, but my git bash is still looking at the permissions of my old account and will not switch to my other account. How do I fix the following error?

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin setDatabase
remote: Permission to lullaby/example.git denied to school-account-barEfu.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/lullaby/example.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I wanted to use account barkotefuye, which has access to the following repository. It is also important to note the repo "example" is private. I used

- user config username -- barkotefuye
- user config email-- myemail@mail.com

Comment: Try authentication with SSH keys, let me know if that worked...

Answer (score 0):

**Changing email and username on git config, does not change account.**

Looks like you don't have permissions to push to that repo. Have you authenticated your account, [see this article](https://help.github.com/en/articles/set-up-git#next-steps-authenticating-with-github-from-git). I'd recommend authenticating [using your SSH keys](https://help.github.com/en/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use#cloning-with-ssh-urls).

Also, the syntax in your commands is slightly wrong, try this:

`git config user.name "Barkot Efuye"`

`git config user.email "email@example.com"`

*Sources: [Setting username](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git#setting-your-email-address-for-a-single-repository), [Setting email address](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git#setting-your-email-address-for-a-single-repository)*

Comment: I tried that method, but it did not change the account. My other account has permissions to push to that repo

Comment: You've tried SSH keys? (Switching email and name on git config DOES NOT switch account)

Comment: I am now getting an error with git add, I get cannot access public/ permission denied